# В День народного единства (,) 4 ноября (,) в городе пройдут различные мероприятия

Tags: пунктуация

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые здесь?
*В День народного единства (,) 4 ноября (,) в городе пройдут различные мероприятия.*
Я считаю, что нужны, поскольку "4 ноября" это уточнение, но хочу быть уверенным.
И всегда, когда встречается название праздника и дата праздника, они отделяются запятыми?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...нужны ли запятые здесь? *В День народного единства (,) 4 ноября
>   (,) в городе пройдут различные мероприятия.*

Нужны. ***4 ноября*** -- пояснительная конструкция.

[Из Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119):

> **§ 23. Пояснительные конструкции**
>
> 1. Слова, поясняющие смысл предшествующего члена предложения, выделяются (или отделяются) знаками препинания (запятыми, тире,
>      двоеточием). Различие между уточняющими и пояснительными членами
>      предложения заключается в том, что если уточнение — это переход от
>      более широкого понятия к более узкому [см. § 22], то **пояснение — это
>      обозначение одного и того же понятия другими словами.** Перед
>      пояснительным членом предложения обычно стоят слова *именно, а именно,
>      то есть* **(при отсутствии в предложении эти слова могут быть
>      вставлены)**...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А то тут от безграмотных текстов уже сомневаться начинаешь в очевидных вещах)

Comment: Слава, это уточнение, а не пояснительная конструкция.

Comment: _Серж: это уточнение, а не пояснительная конструкция._ === Уточнением _это_ было бы, если бы у нас в стране было несколько **Дней народного единства**, а "4 ноября" указывало бы на конкретный день из этих  нескольких. В нашем же случае _это_ -- пояснение ("обозначение одного и того же понятия другими словами").

Comment: Слава, ну ведь 4 ноября и Дней народного единства - не то же самое.

Answer (score 1):

Гораздо лучше будет наоборот: *4 ноября, в День народного единства, ...*

Comment: Золотые слова: и дата указана, и праздник обозначен (уточнен и пояснен), если кто-нибудь забыл.

Comment: Вера,а можно объяснить, что вы имели в виду?!

Comment: Согласен, здесь запятая необходима, т.к. явно идет уточнение.